# How should I style-up absolute PHP code made of echo statements?

Tags: php, html, css

I have this chunk of PHP code, in a file named `receipt.php` :

```
<?php
echo $_POST['desc'] . '<br><br>';

echo 'Transaction ID : ' . $_POST['txnid'] . '<br>';
echo 'Date : ' . $_POST['date'] . '<br>';
echo 'Status : ' . $_POST['fcode'] . '<br>';
echo 'Amount : INR ' . $_POST['amount'] . '<br>';
echo 'Name : ' . $_POST['name'] . '<br>';
echo 'Email ID : ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br>';
echo 'Mobile No. : ' . $_POST['mobile'] . '<br>';
echo 'City : ' . $_POST['city'] . '<br>';
?>
```

The code obviously just simply prints the whole thing in the corner of a blank page. Here's how it roughly looks like in the browser:

[image: PHP snap]

I just want to align the whole thing to the center of the page (center to both top-bottom & left-right) and since the text doesn't look uniformed, I want to make sure both the sides look like they have the same width.

So, to add stylings, do I need to convert/transfer all of my code from my absolute PHP file (`receipt.php`) to a new HTML file (`receipt.html`), then write PHP code in PHP tags & style-up using CSS? Or is there any way to do this in PHP itself?

I've seen topics here and articles which show how to style echo statements - but they don't seem to work for me

Comment: Echo '<pre>' on the first line. Echo '</pre>' on the last line. This will give a proper style. However if you want to customize it more, you need CSS

Comment: So I think I should stick with the CSS option. Do I need to recode this whole in <PHP> tags in a new HTML file to add some CSS?

Comment: if you want to align your text element you can use

Comment: Why not using a `<table>`?

Comment: @MarkusZeller How would a <table> tag help?

Comment: A table will maintain the columns. Think of a spreadsheet like Excel does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the html tags in your php file like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>
<style>
Your styles here...
</style>
<body>

<?php
echo $_POST['desc'] . '<br><br>';

echo 'Transaction ID : ' . $_POST['txnid'] . '<br>';
echo 'Date : ' . $_POST['date'] . '<br>';
echo 'Status : ' . $_POST['fcode'] . '<br>';
echo 'Amount : INR ' . $_POST['amount'] . '<br>';
echo 'Name : ' . $_POST['name'] . '<br>';
echo 'Email ID : ' . $_POST['email'] . '<br>';
echo 'Mobile No. : ' . $_POST['mobile'] . '<br>';
echo 'City : ' . $_POST['city'] . '<br>';
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Then you can add elements classes and style it as you wish

Comment: Thanks @kaize! Also, would that be okay if I copy paste this my `receipt.php` file? Or a new HTML file?

Comment: You can add this directly in your php file no need of HTML

Answer (score 1):

Why not using a `<table>`?
You also can use a mapping for elegant output.

```
$map = [
    'txnid' => 'Transaction ID',
    'date' => 'Date',
    'fcode' => 'Status',
    'amount' => 'Amount : INR',
    'name' => 'Name',
    'email' => 'Email ID',
    'mobile' => 'Mobile No.',
    'city' => 'City'
];

echo '<table>', PHP_EOL;
foreach($map as $key => $description) {
    $value = htmlentities($_POST[$key] ?? 'n/a');
    echo "<tr><td>$description</td><td>$value</td></tr>", PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</table>', PHP_EOL;
```